# Spring boot "oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: invalid identifier" Error while creating table

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, code-first

In spring boot, I create tables of the database using the Code-First approach.
then while running the application, the result for one of tables shows this error:

```
WARN  o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl.handleException - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table statistic add date timestamp" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceExcepti
on: Error executing DDL "alter table statistic add date timestamp" via JDBC Statement]

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

The class entity is as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "statistic")
public class Statistic {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private Long value;
    private Date date;
    private String unit;


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Add  `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` for Date datatype. like `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) private Date date`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java-Oracle - Unable to create specific table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65740469/java-oracle-unable-to-create-specific-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
alter table statistic add date timestamp
                          ----
                          this
```

`date` is a *reserved word* for Oracle **datatype**. Change column name to something else, e.g. `datum`, `c_date`, `statistic_date`, ... and then run

```
alter table statistic add datum timestamp
```

Comment: thanks a lot, right, it was a reserved keyword error, I changed the field name and the problem solved!

Comment: The most popular [reserved words](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612) are `USER` and `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue  and  that solutions do not work for you (like me) please try to set up in properties:

**spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.proto.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy**

I will try to give you the big picture. Table in Oracle does have a column in which has been used the keyword and its name is DATE. I've found 3 ways to solve it but none of them does not work for me. Those approaches such as:

1. Manual escaping by the double quote like ""DATE""
2. Manual escaping using the Hibernate-specific back-tick character like "'DATE'"
3. spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
   This settings leads to issues in other tables so it does not work for me.. maybe there is a specific case.

The problem was with the building names of columns with lower case. Hibernate builds query using the pattern like <alias_table>_."date" - in my case -  but Oracle has returned an error.
Query was sucessufuly executed on the SQLDeveloper when  I change "date" to "DATE". So the problem was the case insensitive for hibernate but it did matter for Oracle.
Properties of Physical strategy allows hibernate to build the query with column name the same like in annotation - it works.
I do not know that this case might occur in other databse than Oracle 12 but Oracle does have it.